# retrieve the index of point in CGAL

Tags: indexing, cgal, triangulation

In the following code, a delaunay triangulation is made from an N dimensional array named **points**. Every element of this array has an index associated with it. For every vertex of the triangulation the nearest vertex is found correctly (without using the libraray: **CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base...**). Now, I want to retrieve the index of each neighbor point with **->info()**, but the way I've implemented that leads to error! How can I do that?

```
#include <vector>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>

using namespace std();

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned int, Kernel> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Kernel, Tds> Triangulation;

typedef Triangulation::Edge_iterator Edge_iterator;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_circulator Vertex_circulator;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;

typedef std::vector<std::pair<Point_2, unsigned> > Vector;

const int N = 16;

int main(){

Vector points;
points.reserve(N);

.... {Some part of code which assignes values to dir[N][2]}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     points.push_back(make_pair(Point_2(dir[i][0], dir[i][1]), i));\\ I want each point to have an index



Triangulation T;

T.insert(points.begin(), points.end());
cout << T.number_of_vertices() <<endl;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

Vertex_handle handle = T.nearest_vertex(points[i]);
cout<<"incidents: \n" <<endl;
cout << handle->point() <<endl<<endl;
Vertex_circulator circulator = T.incident_vertices(handle), done(circulator);
do
   {
    if( !T.is_infinite ( circulator))

    cout << circulator->point() << endl;
    cout << circulator->point()->info()<<endl;
      } while(++circulator != done);
                            }
return 0;}
```

edit: It seems that the origin of the error is primarily because of using the following kernel: **typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2 Triangulation;**

**error**: no matching function for call to        CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2 > >::nearest_vertex(std::pair, unsigned int>&)’

edit 2: when I print the output in two different lines, weired number(96) appears:

```
The code:
cout<<circulator->point()<<endl;
cout<<circulator->info()<<endl;

output(total number of points, 4): 

3.26675 0.733887
2
96
2.02307 0.718587
1
2.33861 1.68862
3
```

when I print the information in one line, the number 96 disappears;

```
cout<<circulator->point()<<"\t"<<circulator->info()<<endl;

3.26675 0.733887    2
2.02307 0.718587    1
2.33861 1.68862 3
```

Comment: The info is not a member of the point class but of the vertex.

Comment: Thank you; So I think circulator->info() must be the right thing; but the error still exists. In the edited version, you can see the first error.

Comment: The error message is self-contained.... `T.nearest_vertex(points[i].first);`

Comment: I know, but without **CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h** that part of code works fine! I think **nearest_vertex** is not defined in **typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned int, Kernel> Vb;**

Comment: Let me be clearer, you have to replace `T.nearest_vertex(points[i])` by `T.nearest_vertex(points[i].first)` as pointed out by the error message.

Comment: Thanks @sloriot, I should have read more carefully your first answer. It solved that problem. But with different methods to print the output, weired number may be printed!

Comment: The weired number was for infinite vertex. Now, every thing works correctly!